# How to have two different chats in two different pages of the same website using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm not really expert yet, anyway thank you for helping me. I created a website with two different pages. Now I want to get two different chats, one for the first page and one for the second. I need to use socket.io. I've actually already implemented the code to get one working chat, but when I type something on this chat, the message appears even in the other. So this means that the two chats are linked each other. That is the problem because I want them to be indipendent. Id est I want them to work with their own pages which have got the send button, the input field for the message and the input field for your name. So the two pages can work alone, but i don't know how.
My code is divided into 2 pages: index.js and chat.js. Here there is Index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
//app setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080, function(){
console.log('ascoltando la richiesta alla porta 8080');
});
//static 
app.use(express.static('public'));
//socket setup
var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('fatta la connessione socket', socket.id);
socket.on('chat', function(data) {
io.emit('chat', data); 
});
socket.on('typing', function(data) {
socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
});
});
```

And here there is the code placed in chat.js (which is the file linked in one html page, the other page is not currently linked with anything):

```
//connessione
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080'); // è una variabile socket diversa da quella in                 index.js
//query
var message= document.getElementById('message'); 
var handle = document.getElementById('handle');
var button = document.getElementById('send');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');
//scrollbar sempre in basso
function updateScroll(){
var element = document.getElementById("output");
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
} 
//emit eventi
button.addEventListener('click',function() {
socket.emit('chat', {
message: message.value,
handle: handle.value
}); 
});
message.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
});
//listen eventi
socket.on('chat', function(data){
if (data.message !== "" & data.handle !== "") {
if (handle.value === data.handle) {
    feedback.innerHTML= "" ;
    output.innerHTML +='<p id=inviato>' +'<span id="utente">'+'Tu' +'</span> <br> ' +    data.message +'</p> <br>';
    updateScroll();
    document.getElementById('message').value='';
} else {
    feedback.innerHTML= "" ;
    output.innerHTML +='<p id=ricevuto>' +'<span id="utente">'+data.handle +'</span> <br> '   + data.message +'</p> <br>';
    updateScroll();
    document.getElementById('message').value='';
}
} 
});
socket.on('typing', function(data) {
feedback.innerHTML = '<p>'+ data + ' sta scrivendo...' + io.engine.clientsCount;
});
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

thank you but I've probably not understood because it doesn't work anymore: when i press the send button, nothing happens.
here there are the two codes updated.
index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

//app setup
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080, function(){
console.log('ascoltando la richiesta alla porta 8080');
});


//static 
app.use(express.static('public'));

//socket setup 

var room1 = io.of('/room1');
var room2 = io.of('/room2');


room1.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('fatta la connessione socket', socket.id);
socket.on('chat', function(data) {
   io.emit('chat', data); 
});
socket.on('typing', function(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
});


});
room2.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('fatta la connessione socket', socket.id);
socket.on('chat', function(data) {
   io.emit('chat', data); 
});
socket.on('typing', function(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
});


});
```

chat.js:

```
//connessione
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/room1');// è una variabile socket       diversa da quella in index.js


//query
var message= document.getElementById('message'); 
var handle = document.getElementById('handle');
var button = document.getElementById('send');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');
//scrollbar sempre in basso
function updateScroll(){
var element = document.getElementById("output");
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}
//emit eventi
button.addEventListener('click',function() {
socket.emit('chat', {
   message: message.value,
   handle: handle.value
}); 
});
message.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
});

//listen eventi
socket.on('chat', function(data){
if (data.message !== "" & data.handle !== "") {
    if (handle.value === data.handle) {
        feedback.innerHTML= "" ;
        output.innerHTML +='<p id=inviato>' +'<span id="utente">'+'Tu' +'</span> <br> ' + data.message +'</p> <br>';
        updateScroll();
        document.getElementById('message').value='';
    } else {
        feedback.innerHTML= "" ;
        output.innerHTML +='<p id=ricevuto>' +'<span id="utente">'+data.handle +'</span> <br> ' + data.message +'</p> <br>';
        updateScroll();
        document.getElementById('message').value='';
    }
} 

});


socket.on('typing', function(data) {
feedback.innerHTML = '<p>'+ data + ' sta scrivendo...' + io.engine.clientsCount;
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I am late, holiday struggles :P
Anyway, you have to readjust how you send messages, change `io.emit(..., ...)` to `socket.broadcast.emit(..., ...)`